# Allow non-admin users to mount drives via nautilus

Tags: mount, nautilus, administration, privileges

I want to give mount privilege to the non-admin users to mount the drives via nautilus. I don't want them to give other admin privilege. I also don't want to use setuid method.

How can I achieve this? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the default policy. There are three ways to achieve this:

### By giving privilege to a group

1. First create a group `mounter` by using this command:

   ```
    sudo addgroup mounter
   ```
2. Then add the non-admin users to this group. For examle, I'm adding non-admin user `normal` to this group.

   ```
    sudo adduser normal mounter
   ```
3. Then open the policy file with admin privilege.

   ```
    gksu gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
   ```
4. At the top of the file there is a section like this:

   ```
   [Mounting, checking, etc. of internal drives]
   Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo;
   Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-*;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-ata-smart*
   ResultActive=yes
   ```

   Add `unix-group:mounter;` after `Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo;` at the first line of the section. The changed section will look like this

   ```
   [Mounting, checking, etc. of internal drives]
   Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo;unix-group:mounter;
   Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-*;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-ata-smart*
   ResultActive=yes
   ```

That's it. Now the non-admin users can mount the drives without requiring admin-password. They only need to be added to the `mounter` group. Note to add a user `novice` to the group `mounter`, execute this command: `sudo adduser novice mounter`.

### By giving privilege to specific user

If you don't want to create another group, you can just add their user name (login name) in that file.

1. Open the policy file with admin privilege. You can type this command in a terminal or in the dash prompt by Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>.

   ```
    gksu gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
   ```
2. Then add `unix-user:<login-name>` at the `Identity` line in the section `[Mounting, checking, etc. of internal drives]`. ***Remember to use the login name of the user, not the literal .***. For example, if you want to give user `tester` this privilege, the line will be look like below

   ```
   [Mounting, checking, etc. of internal drives]
   Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo;unix-user:tester;
   Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-*;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-ata-smart*
   ResultActive=yes
   ```
3. Save the file and exit gedit.

### By giving privilege to all users

The above two methods will not work for the default guess user in Ubuntu. Because, the guest user is created dynamically upon login and get deleted after logout.

To workaround this, You can give all users this privilege.

1. Open the policy file with admin privilege. You can type this command in a terminal or in the dash prompt by Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>.

   ```
    gksu gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
   ```
2. Then add `unix-user:*` at the `Identity` line in the section `[Mounting, checking, etc. of internal drives]`. After modification the section will look like below:

   ```
   [Mounting, checking, etc. of internal drives]
   Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo;unix-user:*;
   Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-*;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-ata-smart*
   ResultActive=yes
   ```
3. Save the file and exit gedit.

---

#### UPDATES

1. Tested in 14.04. It works the way it is described in the answer

Comment: Is this still valid for 14.04? I edited the file and put my username in but trying to mount a device in nautilus results in the error `mount: only root can mount...`

Comment: @byf-ferdy I'll check and edit it. There is subtle change in it

Comment: @byf-ferdy, I've just tested on 14.04. Works as mentioned here. I've used the last method, i.e adding `unix-user:*`. Check, if your drive or volume is listed in `/etc/fstab`. If that is the case, You can't mount this way

Comment: yes I did add it in my `fstab` how could I mount it in this case as a normal user?

Comment: I believe this question was asked already. Search the site. or if you don't find anything, then ask a new question. Basically, you need to specify some options in `/etc/fstab` files. the main options is `users` which enable all users to mount. please have a look at mount manual `man mount`

Comment: Tested last option (By giving privilege to all users) with Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit. Works as described.