# How to mount partitions in nautilus as a normal user?

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions, nautilus, encryption

I have made several partitions on my hard disk. One is encrypted (LUKS) and contains my sensitive data. I don't want this partition to be mounted permanently (by automounting it via fstab), only when I (or another user) need(s) it.

Also, I want my partitions to be accessible for normal users through my file-manager Nautilus. This is because several normal users (who do not, and will not use terminal commands such as sudo and mount) are using this system as well, and I want them to be able to access it through the file-manager.

So basically, I want two things: 
- mount permissions for normal users
- mount capability through the file manager Nautilus for normal users.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself:
[Allow non-admin users to mount drives via nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185718/allow-non-admin-users-to-mount-drives-via-nautilus). I can't really copy and paste the steps described in that post, so please just read that one, and you'll be on your way!

Great! Now my system is perfect and safe!

Comment: it will be better if you mention steps you followed in your answer